# Validar cantidad de caracteres en pasword y el modal no aparece al validar formulario HTML5, CSS3 y JS

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, formularios

como consigna me piden que haga un formulario de registro, donde se validen los datos ingresados mediante JS (no html) pero sin utilizar librerías; y que, al validar el formulario con un button me muestre un modal indicando que el registro fue exitoso.

No logro que valide en los campos "Contraseña" y "Repetir contraseña" (me aparece continuamente que ingrese minimo 6 caracteres, ponga la cantidad y tipo que ponga), y tampoco que aparezca el modal al validar el formulario.
Adjunto el código a ver si alguien puede decirme donde estoy errando.

**Esto es HTML**

```
                <label for="contrasena">(*) Contraseña: </label>
                <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasenaInput" placeholder="Escriba su contraseña">
                <p class="errorContrasena" id="errorContrasena" style="display:none;color: red;" ></p>
                <label for="recontrasena">(*) Repita su contraseña: </label>
                <input type="password" name="recontrasena" id="recontrasenaInput" placeholder="Repita su contraseña">
                <p class="errorRecontrasena" id="errorRecontrasena" style="display:none;color: red;" ></p>
            </div>
            <p>(*) Campos obligatorios</p>
            <button id="submit" onclick="modal()">Registrar usuario</button>

            <div id="modal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Registro exitoso. Muchas gracias.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
```

**Esto es JS**

```
    window.onload = function () {

  function validaPass(e){
    const pass = document.getElementById('contrasenaInput');
    var errorPass = document.getElementById('errorContrasena');
    if(pass.value.length <= 5){
      pass.style.borderColor= "red";
      errorPass.style.display='block';
      errorPass.innerHTML='Debe ingresar una contraseña de al menos 6 caracteres';
      error = true;
    }
  }

  function validaRepass(e){
    const repass = document.getElementById('recontrasenaInput');
    var errorRepass = document.getElementById('errorRecontrasena');
    if(repass.value !== pass.value){
      repass.style.borderColor= "red";
      errorRepass.style.display='block';
      errorRepass.innerHTML='Las contraseñas ingresadas deben coincidir';
      error = true;
    }
  }

  var form = document.getElementById("formulario");
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (evento) {
      error=false;
      evento.preventDefault();
      validaPass();
      validaRepass();
      if(!error) modal.style.display = "block";
  })    

var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

button.onclick = function modal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
```

Comment: Y donde haces la validación, esto solo es html, por favor lee como hacer un [example]

Comment: La validación la hago desde javascript, evidentemente no terminaste de leer el código, no es sólo html. Incluí mucho código porque me pareció relevante al momento de las validaciones, pero lo edito para que se vea sólo lo que no funciona.